# Let $X= (0,1) \cup(2,3)$ be an open set $f$ is continuous function on it

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

A function defined on

> $X=(0,1) \cup(2,3)$ is open set in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$.

Then the range of function is

> $1)$ uncountable number of point
>
> $2)$ Countably infinite number of points
>
> $3)$ atmost 2 points
>
> $4)$ atmost 1 point

Here in this question The co-domain is not given rather it is $\mathbb{R}$ or something else ,

If we consider the co domain $\mathbb{R}$ then ,The function is continous if the range is a singleton set then its inverse image should be closed (singleton set is closed in $\mathbb{R}$) but the set is open so it can't be true ,same will be for two point option so option 3th and 4th is not true.

But if i consider $f$ as a constant function then 4th option is true ,but this condition works on Connected set while the given domain is not connected , next i am not getting how to solve

Please help

Comment: $(0,1),(2,3),(0,1)\cup (2,3)$ are all closed in $X$ (even though they are not closed in $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'$ is the null function, the restriction of $f$ to any connected subset of $X$ is constant. So, $f|_{(0,1)}$ and $f|_{(2,3)}$ are constant functions and therefore the range of $f$ consists of $2$ points, at most. And, of course, in some cases, it consists of *exactly* $2$ points.

Comment: can we define this function ,Does this function still continious?

Comment: Sure. Take$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\in(0,1)\\1&\text{ if }x\in(2,3)\end{cases}$$for instance.

Comment: I was thinking the defination of continuity ,left and right limit.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thankyou sir ,i got it